# InvalidArgumentException while returning a value

Tags: java, unit-testing, jmockit

I am new to JMockit. I have recently tried writing unit tests where I have to test a system method that takes an argument. Inside the method under test the argument instance chains multiple of its methods to return a Collection object.

The code below simulates the exact situation I am facing. I am using **jmockit-1.9**

**The system under test**

```
public class SystemUnderTest {

    public void doSomething(Dependency dependency) {
        List<String> list = dependency.getMap().get("some-key");
        System.out.println("got list -> " + list);
    }
}
```

**Dependency class**

```
public class Dependency {       
    private Map<String, List<String>> map;    
    public Map<String, List<String>> getMap() {
        return map;
    }    
    public void setMap(Map<String, List<String>> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }
}
```

**Test**

```
@Test
public void testDoSomething(
        @Mocked Dependency dependency,
        @Mocked Map<String, List<String>> map,
        @Mocked List<String> list
        ) {

    new NonStrictExpectations() {{
        dependency.getMap(); result = map;
        map.get(anyString); result = list; //exception occurs here  
    }};

    SystemUnderTest sut = new SystemUnderTest();        
    sut.doSomething(dependency);        
}
```

When I run the test, I get the following exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid return value for method returning class java.util.HashMap
```

at this line

```
 map.get(anyString); result = list;
```

As it can be clearly see, the return type of `map.get()` should be a `List` but it says that the method is returning a `HashMap`.

What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciated;

Comment: What and where is `result` declared as?

Comment: `result` is an internal field of `Expectations` class. It stores the object that will be returned when that particular method is invoked. http://javadox.com/org.jmockit/jmockit/1.9/mockit/Expectations.html

Comment: It's a weird construct. Remember that assigning a value to a field with `result = list;` cannot possibly throw an exception in Java. So the exception thrown in this line is thrown by `map.get(anyString);` . And it is probably about what was done with the previous instruction, `result = map;` since if that was incorrect, there was no possible way to complain about it with the assignment itself, remember, it cannot throw an exception. So the one to throw an exception needs to be the next method call. Why it doesn't like it is a mystery to me, but maybe you can better focus on the right place.

Comment: You're using a *very* old version of JMockit...